# How to send cookies with fetch and fix 404 post error?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

How to send cookies with fetch and fix 404 post error?
Hello. I'm trying to send a post to a server that uses a jwt token for authorization, but I get a post 404.
Here is the logic for setting the token and the user:

```
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  const jwtToken = req.cookies.JWT_TOKEN;

  if(!jwtToken) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  jwt.verify(jwtToken, SECRET, (err, decoded)=>{
    if(err) {
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    const sessionData = decoded.data;
    let userId;

    if (sessionData['modx.user.contextTokens']) {
      if (sessionData['modx.user.contextTokens']['web'] > 0) {
        userId = sessionData['modx.user.contextTokens']['web'];
      }else if($dataarr['modx.user.contextTokens']['mgr'] > 0) {
        userId = sessionData['modx.user.contextTokens']['mgr'];
      } else {
        return redirect('/signin');
      }
    }

    req.user = {userId};
    next();
  });
});

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  if (!req.user || !req.user.userId) {
    next(new Error('Access Denied'));
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Here is the get request that was already here and it works:

```
app.get("/:id?", function(req, res){
  const room = {id:parseInt(req.params.id||0)};
  const userid = req.user.userId;

  console.log('USEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEER ID', userid);

  pool.query("SELECT * FROM modx_user_attributes WHERE id = ?", [userid], function(err, [userData]) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    //console.log('userData', userData);

    const token = jwt.sign({
      data: {userId: userid},
    }, SECRET);

    res.render("index.hbs", {
        appdata: {token, room, user: userData},
        final scripts,
    });
  });
});
```

And here is my point, but I can't reach it:

```
app.post('/writeVideo', (req, res) => {
    req.video.mv('test.wav', (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send({
          success: 'file write'
        })
      }
    });
})
```

And here I am trying to knock on the point:

```
fetch('/writeVideo', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
              'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: {
              user: {
                userId: 8
              },
              video: audioBlob
            }
          }).then(data => data.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

I read a little, they advise just using credentials: 'same-origin' || 'include', however it didn't work for me, I tried setting Cookie headers: 'JWT_TOKEN=token' in different ways - didn't work. Please tell me how should I proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: To get access to req.cookies you need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser which I am presuming you are if not that could be your first issue?

Comment: @HugoDos hey, now i have no problem with this question, i fixed this, thx u. This code very broken and i need use fetch('/video/writeVideo') for call my endpoint)